# To get two values as input in php

Tags: php

In my below php code the student rollno and name is got as input and the student address and mark will be displayed based on it. But the code works only if i give only 1 input.

```
<?php 

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

 $rollno  = $_GET['rollno'];
$name  = $_GET['name'];


 require_once('dbConnect.php');

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM colleges WHERE rollno='".$rollno."'" and name='".$name."'";

 $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 $res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

 $result = array();

 array_push($result,array(

 "address"=>$res['address'],
 "marks"=>$res['marks']
 )
 );

 echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

 mysqli_close($con);

 }
```

Comment: All this - including sql injection - could be avoided / solved if you used prepared statements.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM colleges WHERE rollno='".$rollno."'" and name='".$name."'";.. error in this line

Answer (score 0):

replace `$sql = "SELECT * FROM colleges WHERE rollno='".$rollno."'" and name='".$name."'";`

To

```
"SELECT * FROM colleges WHERE rollno='".$rollno."' and name='".$name."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM colleges WHERE rollno='".$rollno."'" and name='".$name."'";

Corrected :

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM colleges WHERE rollno='".$rollno."' and name='".$name."'";

But for better you should use prepared statements
Example

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "db_name");
$query = "SELECT * FROM colleges WHERE rollno=? AND name=?"; 
$params = array($rollno,$name); 
mysqli_prepared_query($link,$query,"ss",$params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check and make sure the line $sql query is correct in your code because it is incorrect in your question.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM colleges WHERE rollno='".$rollno."'" and name='".$name."'";
```

Should be

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM colleges WHERE rollno='" . $rollno . "' and name='" . $name ."'";
```

Or use single quotes for improved performance as:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM colleges WHERE rollno = "' . $rollno .'" and name= "' . $name ."';
```

Secondly, what's the data type of your$rollno, if its not string then consider removing the single quotes surrounding it.

Thirdly, make sure both columns rollno and name have variables at all time, with the correct query else you all get a Null result.

Finally, I strongly suggest you use a pdo and its prepared statement next time.